# Travis-CI "The command "bundle exec rake" exited with 1." + mystery 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, neo4j, travis-ci, rspec3, neo4j.rb

`bundle exec rake` runs all tests perfectly fine *locally*. However, Travis CI keeps blowing up with `Problem accessing /authentication` without giving much more info to go on. Here's one of the failed builds: https://travis-ci.org/Nase00/Horizon/builds/48094102 For the life of me, I cannot figure out what is causing an authentication error when Travis tries to run `bundle exec rake`.

Here's the project repo: https://github.com/Nase00/Horizon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of Neo4j Travis uses (**UPDATE:** they use 1.9.4, not supported) but I'm going to guess that it's a bit older than what Neo4j.rb supports. I'm one of the core maintainers and built the Neo4j 2.2 auth support that's fouling you up, but I tested it with different versions, going back to the early 2.1 subversions and had no trouble.

The best practice is to not use Travis's Neo4j at all. Instead, configure Travis to install the same version of the database you're using for dev and production. As a bonus, the rake task that installs Neo also disables auth in 2.2, so you don't have to deal with that at all. It's not that we're against auth, it's that we think of the rake install and config tasks as convenient features for dev/test environment, not production, so no auth seems like a reasonable default.

Take a peak at our `.travis.yml` file to see how we do the installation. https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/blob/master/.travis.yml. An abstract that'll solve your issue:

```
script:
  - "bundle exec rake neo4j:install['community-2.2.0-M02'] neo4j:start default --trace"
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.0.0
```

Swap the `community-2.2.0-M02` for whatever version you want to use. I'd have to check again but from what I remember, we are compatible with versions as far back as 2.1.2. I apologize for this not being posted in our docs -- it should be.

I **very strongly** recommend using Ruby 2.2.0 with Neo4j.rb. We generate a lot of symbols during Cypher queries that won't be garbage collected otherwise.

**EDIT for a little more info**

The very first thing the auth module does is check for the presence of the authentication REST endpoint. In all of the versions of Neo4j I tested, it didn't give an error like that, it just returned an empty body, which we interpret as a sign that auth is either unsupported or disabled.

**Aftermath Edit**

Travis support confirmed their provided Neo4j version is 1.9.4.

Comment: I've also just pushed a patch version 4.0.1 which may fix this issue

Comment: Though it just occurred to me that it might be because the neo4j version is before 2.x, which the gem doesn't support

Comment: I just emailed Travis to see what version they're running. Wouldn't be surprised if it was still 1.9.