# Travis CI : The command "bundle exec rake" exited with 1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, travis-ci

I don't seem to understand the issue, everything works fine locally but when pushed to git travis does not pass it and give error `The command "bundle exec rake" exited with 1`.
Here is my PR https://github.com/shakacode/react-webpack-rails-tutorial/pull/450

And here is the travis CI link https://travis-ci.org/shakacode/react-webpack-rails-tutorial/builds/448461518?utm_source=github_status&utm_medium=notification

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119147/travis-ci-the-command-bundle-exec-rake-exited-with-1-mystery-404-error and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28843054/travis-ci-the-command-bundle-exec-rake-exited-with-1?rq=1?

Comment: i have looked into these questions, tried their solution but doesn't work for me